# hebrew text inside NavigateUrl

Tags: asp.net, utf-8, hebrew

It seems like when I input hebrew text inside asp:HyperLink on NavigateUrl property, it gets coded into its UTF8 coding, instead of just presenting me the hebrew word (like on regular non runat server link on same page).

So for

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hypID" runat="server" NavigateUrl="שלום" />
```

I get

```
<a id="cphMiddle_repRightCol_hypCat_0" href="%d7%a9%d7%9c%d7%95%d7%9d">text</a>
```

Output on page, instead of

```
<a id="cphMiddle_repRightCol_hypCat_0" href="שלום">
text</a>
```

Can this be avoided?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could try using the HTML control equivalent, which is less constricting:

```
<a runat="server" href="שלום" ..
```

**EDIT**: Also, have you setup the correct encoding for the site as a whole?  Via: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39d1w2xf.aspx

Comment: nope. won't do, as soon as I put runat="server", same outcome.

Comment: Really?  Very interesting....  Do you need the server-side capabilities of a link?  You could just use <a>.  Also, have you setup the globalization features to the correct encoding?  See link in edited response above.

Comment: Put the globalization. Not helping, still links are encoded. Very weird thing. Sometimes I do need the server capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, `NavigateUrl` will encode the url in UTF8.
What you CAN do, is omit the NavigateUrl altogether and use the href tag instead:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hypID" runat="server" href="שלום" Text="Link" />
```

Which will render it like this:

```
<a id="hypID" href="שלום">Link</a>
```

Hope it helps... ובהצלחה